# Ubuntu not found process gunicorn after restart session of putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu, background-process

I run gunicorn in Ubuntu with this command.

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 django_project.wsgi
```

I press **Ctrl+z** then I use command **bg** it can show gunicorn process.

After that, I close putty and open putty again when I use command **bg** it show

```
bash: bg: current: no such job
```

I use command.

```
pkill gunicorn
```

when I start gunicorn by using **gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 django_project.wsgi** again it show error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_project'
```

Which before restart session of putty it have no this error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The good way to put some service in background is to use `nohup` and `&` :

```
nohup gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 django_project.wsgi >logs.log 2>errs.log &
```

`nohup` will deattach the program from terminal
`&` will put the program in background

About not found error check if you are in the same directory where the module is